# Wrapper classes and call by reference in java

Tags: java

Below is my code:

```
class Demo{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i = new Integer(12);

    System.out.println(i);

    modify(i);

    System.out.println(i);

}
private static void modify(Integer i) {

    i= i + 1;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

}

The OUTPUT of the above CODE is 
12
12
but as  I know, we are passing the wrapper object "i", it means it should be "Call by reference",Then the value should change to 13.but its 12.
Any one has proper explanation for this?

Comment: I get the output: `12 13 12`.

Comment: The code should print three values, not two.

Comment: Java is [pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

Comment: i=i+1 is being converted to: i= Integer.valueOf(i.intValue()+1); so it's a completely new object. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 9):

References are passed by value, and besides of that Integer is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java).

When passing `i` to the method `modify` the value of the reference is passed (the reference is local to that method) and when you assign another object to it you only modify that local reference/variable holding the reference. The original remains unchanged.

Immutable means that an object once created / instantiated it not possible to change its state any more.

Comment: The immutability of `Integer`s is not significant here.

Comment: @arshajii I mentioned that because obviously the intention was to modify it hence the use of ***besides of that***

Answer (score 7):

This line of code in the `modify` method:

```
    i= i + 1;
```

is operating on an `Integer`, not an `int`. It does the following:

1. unbox `i` to an int value
2. add 1 to that value
3. box the result into another `Integer` object
4. assign the resulting `Integer` to `i` (thus changing what object `i` references)

Since object references are passed by value, the action taken in the `modify` method does not change the variable that was used as an argument in the call to `modify`. Thus the main routine will still print `12` after the method returns.

If you wanted to change the object itself, you would have to pass a mutable object (as others have mentioned, `Integer` is immutable) and you would have to call a mutator method or directly modify a field. For instance:

```
class Demo{
    static class IntHolder {
        private int value;
        public IntHolder(int i) {
            value = i;
        }
        public IntHolder add(int i) {
            value += i;
            return this;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntHolder i = new IntHolder(12);

        System.out.println(i);

        modify(i);

        System.out.println(i);

    }
    private static void modify(IntHolder i) {

        i.add(1);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper classes are immutable, so operations like addition and subtraction create a new object and not modify the old.

If you want to pass a primitive by reference, one way to do it is pass a single element array:

```
int[] i= new int[1]{12};
...
private static void modify(int[] i) {

    i[0]= i[0] + 1;
    System.out.println(i[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is always pass-by-value. The difficult thing can be to understand that Java passes objects as references and those references are passed by value.

Check it out:

[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

check my eclipse it give output 12 13 12 .The modify method pass-by-value 12  then the  `i= i + 1;` it add one the .

```
package com.demo.swain;

public class Demo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer i = new Integer(12);

            System.out.println(i);

            modify(i);

            System.out.println(i);

        }
        private static void modify(Integer i) {

            i= i + 1;
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        }

Output:12
       13
       12
```

[image]I strongly talking this code not give output 12 ,12 .

Comment: How is this an answer to OP's question (which was why the second output from `main` was 12 instead of 13).

Comment: @TedHopp i try my ubuntu os and eclipse IDE it give output 12 13 12 .i sure if you try this you get output 12 13 12 . modify(i); pass value 12 then intialize i=12+1 it give 13

Comment: Yes, I'm not suggesting that the output is anything different than what you say. However, if all you are saying is that OP reported incorrect output, that should be posted as a comment, not an answer. (In my opinion, OP was focused on why the last output from `main()` was not 13.)

Comment: yes regarding OUT-PUT you are correct user3075488.that was not a problem.it was my mistake where i mentioned wrong output.but my question was regarding ,Whether 'Integer' works with pass by reference or not.